# Why can you use list variables for indexing but not a literal list?

Tags: python, indexing, typeerror

In the following code, I have an array `arr` that I'd like to one-hot encode for the integers 0-9. I've put this array into another array `arrs` that will hold more than one array (one array used to simplify things). I would like to iterate through these arrays (again, here there is just the one) and one-hot encode as below. The for loop works just fine. But I found that if I attempt the syntax inside the for loop "manually", I get a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. What's going on under the hood? I suspect this is happening because of the way the compiler works?

```
import numpy as np

arr = [0,1,4,7,9]
arrs = [arr]
results = np.zeros((len(arrs), 10))
print(results) # [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]


for i, seq in enumerate(arrs):
    print(i) # 0
    print(seq) # [0, 1, 4, 7, 9]
    results[i, seq] = 1
print(results) # [[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]]

#When I do the above "manually" I get a TypeError
results = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
results[0,[0, 1, 4, 7, 9]] = 1
print(results)
```

Comment: Your only mistake is not converting `results` to a numpy array. Numpy supports more complex array slicing than python's lists.

Comment: It worked on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy has special indexing that enable it to interpret a sequence as a second parameter to indexing.
You could just stay with a numpy array, but if you want to do it with a python list:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [0,1,4,7,9]
arrs = [arr]
results = np.zeros((len(arrs), 10))
print(results) # [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]


for i, seq in enumerate(arrs):
    print(i) # 0
    print(seq) # [0, 1, 4, 7, 9]
    results[i, seq] = 1
print(results) # [[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]]

#When I do the above "manually" I get a TypeError

results = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

#this is taking place in numpy behind the scenes
nums = [0, 1, 4, 7, 9] #indices to update
for index in nums:
  results[0][index] = 1

print(results) #[[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`x[y]` is equivalent to `x.__getitem__(y)`. There is no universal prohibition on using lists as indices; that's just a prohibition made by `list.__getitem__`. Other types are free to accept or reject what ever they like as an index.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I marked deseuler's answer as the correct answer because he points out a difference between numpy arrays and lists (and somehow I had overlooked that I was using two different data structures). But also, I think your answer alludes to the why of the difference after reading his answer. You may think about just joining these two answers.